# How can I get a page to automatically reload within a Google App Script web app (Html page)?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

How can I get a link to automatically reload within a Google App Script web app (Html page)?

The first page (linkPage.html) is a list of links. It is dynamically generated based upon spreadsheet values.

The user clicks one of the links (link A) and goes to the second page (form1).  The username is written to a cell on the row of the spreadsheet that matches the link clicked(Lock()).  If someone else should pull up the 'link page', they should see the other username next to the link that user is currently editing.  The link page needs to be reloaded anytime any user loads the page to show if that link is being edited.
example:

```
   form     user
   Link A   Bob
   Link B   
   Link C   Fred
   Link D
```

However, when Bob exits the form (which goes directly back to the Link page), his username is removed from the cell on the spreadsheet(Unlock()), but Bob is still shown as the user for Link A on linkPage unless he manually reloads (F5) the link page.  How can I get the link page to automatically refresh/reload every time the page is accessed?  Bob and Fred must be able to see if the other user is editing one of the links.

form1.html (in the script tags at the bottom)

```
window.onload=function WindowLoad(event){
  Lock();
}

function exitForm(){
  Unlock();
  window.top.location.href=strUrl+"?page=linkPage";
  // window.top.location.replace(strUrl+"?page=linkPage"); (doesn't refresh)
  // tried creating element and using a.click() ... (doesn't refresh)
}
```

I tried using the window.location.hash and the localStorage inside the linkPage.html window.onload area- it loads once, then reloads a blank page.

Comment: I think you can resolve this by having the app periodically request status updates from google scripts.  Then the google scripts function can refresh your pages with the latest status update taken from the cells of the spreadsheet via the .withSuccessHandler.

Comment: Thanks for you help.  I am not sure I follow @Cooper.  Are you suggesting to add an onEdit() trigger to the linkPage?  Or just any function to check something in the spreadsheet and use the .withSuccessHandler to call it.  As long as it returns something it will refresh?

Comment: You said `How can I get a link to automatically reload within a Google App Script web app (Html page)?` and I'm suggest that you use the javascript timer functions to request a status update with google.script.run and then the google script function can respond via the withSuccessHandler.